# sql return data from select statement and insert to table variable at the same time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

```
declare @RelevantMachines Table (MachineId int)

Select MachineId, ClusterId, MachineGuid, MachineName, RegisteredDate, MachineDetail, LastServiceCall, MachineType as MachineTypeId, ProductSetId
From PatchHub.Machine
Where ClusterId = @ClusterId
```

I would like to be able to return the select statement as a result set whilst at the same time populating the table variable with all of the returned rows MachineId values, this is in sql server 2008. How could you achieve this without running the select statement twice?

Comment: Is there a special reason you can't run it twice, or is it just something you would rather not do if possible?

Comment: running it twice would take twice as long, my application needs the returned set and the rest of the stored proc would benifit from having a stored set of just the machineId's rather than having to do this select statement again

Comment: You can insert & select atomically with OUTPUT but you would need to add all the columns to your table variable, if you don't want that you could select & insert the IDs in the the variable then select from that inner joined to the underlying table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it in a single SELECT, I think the next best thing would be something like this:

```
declare @result table (
MachineId int, 
ClusterId int, 
MachineGuid guid, 
MachineName varchar(100), 
RegisteredDate datetime, 
MachineDetail varchar(1000), 
LastServiceCall int, 
MachineType int, 
ProductSetId int)

Select MachineId, ClusterId, MachineGuid, MachineName, RegisteredDate, MachineDetail, LastServiceCall, MachineType as MachineTypeId, ProductSetId
into @result
From PatchHub.Machine
Where ClusterId = @ClusterId

select * from @result

/* use @result table */
```

Comment: yeh that's what I was doing but it didn't improve the performance like I had hoped, ah well nevermind, thanks anyway

Comment: If the table variable has the same columns as the select you can do it in one go; `insert @result output inserted.* select xxx from xxx`

Comment: @AlexK. I didn't think of that. Your comment might be what the OP is looking for, you should write that as an answer.